# java.lang.NullPointerException en aplicación de escritorio

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, eclipse

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio con java y base de datos mysql
pero cuando compilo el try y catch me captura un error que es `java.lang.NullPointerException` y no se llena el jtable pero sí guarda los datos que inserto en los textbox y en los combos antes de que ponga el try catch me marcaba error en la siguiente línea.

```
 fila.addElement(cliente.getNacionalidad().getNombre());
```

el codigo de la clase Nacionalidad:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_nacionalidad")
public class Nacionalidad implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="nac_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nac_nom")
    private String nombre;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

el codigo de la clase cliente:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="cli_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="cli_nom")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="prof_ape")
    private String apellido;
    @Column(name="prof_tel")
    private String telefono;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="dis_id")
    private Distrito distrito;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="nac_id")
    private Nacionalidad nacionalidad;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public Distrito getDistrito() {
        return distrito;
    }
    public void setDistrito(Distrito distrito) {
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }

    public Nacionalidad getNacionalidad() {
        return nacionalidad;
    }
    public void setNacionalidad(Nacionalidad nacionalidad) {
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    }



}
```

mi código completo es:

```
public class UICliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private List<Nacionalidad> listaNacionalidad;
    private List<Distrito> listaDistrito;
    private List<Cliente> listaCliente;


    private DefaultTableModel modelCliente;

    public UICliente() {
        initComponents();
        cargarNacionalidades();
        cargarDistritos();
        cargarClientes();
    }


    private void cargarClientes(){
        try{
        modelCliente = (DefaultTableModel)this.tblCliente.getModel();         
        ClienteService clienteService = ServiceLocate.getClienteService();
        listaCliente = clienteService.listarTodo();

        modelCliente.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        for(Cliente cliente:listaCliente){
            Vector fila = new Vector();
            fila.addElement(cliente.getId());
            fila.addElement(cliente.getNombre());
            fila.addElement(cliente.getApellido());
            fila.addElement(cliente.getTelefono());
            fila.addElement(cliente.getNacionalidad().getNombre());//Navegabilidad
            fila.addElement(cliente.getDistrito().getNombre()); //Navegabilidad


            modelCliente.addRow(fila);
        }}catch(Exception excepcion){
                     System.out.println("El objeto error es de tipo " + excepcion);
        }
    }

    private void cargarDistritos(){
        DistritoService distritoService = ServiceLocate.getDistritoService();
        listaDistrito = distritoService.listarTodos();
        for(Distrito distrito:listaDistrito){
            this.cboDistrito.addItem(distrito.getNombre());
        }
    }
      private void cargarNacionalidades(){
        NacionalidadService nacionalidadService = ServiceLocate.getNacionalidadService();
        listaNacionalidad = nacionalidadService.listarTodos();
        for(Nacionalidad nacionalidad:listaNacionalidad){
            this.cboNacionalidad.addItem(nacionalidad.getNombre());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtNombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cboDistrito = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblCliente = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtApellido = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtTelefono = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cboNacionalidad = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Cliente");

        jLabel1.setText("Nombre");

        jLabel2.setText("Profesion");

        tblCliente.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Id", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Telefono", "Profesion", "Nacionalidad"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblCliente);

        jButton1.setText("Agregar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Apellido");

        jLabel4.setText("Telefono");

        jLabel5.setText("Nacionalidad");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(txtNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 234, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(txtApellido))
                                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(txtTelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(cboNacionalidad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(cboDistrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, 225, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 524, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(txtNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(txtApellido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(txtTelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(cboDistrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(cboNacionalidad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        ClienteService clienteService = ServiceLocate.getClienteService();

        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setNombre(this.txtNombre.getText());
         cliente.setApellido(this.txtApellido.getText());
          cliente.setTelefono(this.txtTelefono.getText());
        Distrito distrito = new Distrito();
        distrito.setId(listaDistrito.get(this.cboDistrito.getSelectedIndex()).getId());
        cliente.setDistrito(distrito);
          Nacionalidad nacionalidad = new Nacionalidad();
        nacionalidad.setId(listaNacionalidad.get(this.cboNacionalidad.getSelectedIndex()).getId());
        cliente.setNacionalidad(nacionalidad);

        clienteService.crear(cliente);

        this.txtNombre.setText("");
         this.txtApellido.setText("");
          this.txtTelefono.setText("");
        this.cboDistrito.setSelectedIndex(0);
        this.cboNacionalidad.setSelectedIndex(0);
        this.txtNombre.requestFocus();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Profesor Registrado");

        cargarClientes();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UICliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UICliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UICliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UICliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UICliente().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `cliente.getNacionalidad()` es distinto de null? lo has comprobado?

Comment: en la base de datos? lo hice igual a distrito  ya que ambos son combos tienen todo igual por eso es que no se que esta mal en la base de datos esta marcado como nn(notnull)

Comment: me refiero a q si cuando haces por ejemplo `if(cliente.getNacionalidad()){}` entraria al condicional?. porq en `fila.addElement()` debe recibir como argumento diferente de NULL

Comment: en que parte del codigo deberia usar ese if ?

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu clase `Cliente`, y más específicamente el método `getDistrito()` de la misma? Ese método trabaja con objetos del tipo `Distrito`? ¿El objeto `Distrito` posee un método `getNombre()`?

Comment: ya edite y puse la clase cliente y nacionalidad

Comment: Es posible que el cliente no tnega nacionalidad, asi como dice @SamirLlorente. Has verificado que efectivamente tenga una asociada? `for(Cliente cliente : listaCliente){ if(cliente.getNacionalidad() == null){ System.out.println("El cliente no tiene nacionalidad asociada"); } }`

Comment: Revisando el código, no le estás asignando un `nombre` a la instancia de `Nacionalidad` en ningún momento. Aquí tú creas la instancia y le asignas un `id`: `Nacionalidad nacionalidad = new Nacionalidad(); nacionalidad.setId(listaNacionalidad.get(this.cboNacionalidad.getSelectedIndex()).getId()); cliente.setNacionalidad(nacionalidad);` pero **nunca le asignas el `nombre`, por tanto su atributo `nombre` es nulo**. Convendría que depures lo que hay dentro de tu objeto `nacionalidad`, puede que en efecto veas que tiene atributos `null`. Por eso al intentar obtenerlo con `getNombre()` tienes el NPE

Comment: Hola a todos gracias por sus respuestas ya lo resolvi lo que pasaba es que habia hecho un registro en la tabla cliente y en la columna nacionalidad habia un registro con el valor null y por eso no me queria cargar la tabla despues al modificar los registros de la tabla y le puse valores a los campos que estaban con null se soluciono el problema

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)